How to show html tag in the react-pdf plugin?
value: "1. Delivery Term - 30 days 2. Payment Term - 20 days 3. Item Tax 10%  IGST"
How to show this type of string value to normal html in the pdf?
I have tried using html-parser plugin but does not show the value.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

[
{
"label": "In Words: ",
"value": "Six hundred eighty-eight thousand two hundred twelve Rupees ninety-five Paisa Only"
},
{
"label": "Terms and Conditions:",
"value": "1. Delivery Term - 30 days 2. Payment Term - 20 days 3. Item Tax 10%  IGST"
}
] Here the term value is came with  tag and also , and others HTML tags. I want this to appear in the pdf properly. for example: If the text came with a strong tag then the text shows as bold. how can I achieve this?
